# Why is the imshow function not working properly in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to display an image with matlab. From what I understand, the imshow function is supposed to do this, but for some reason it's not working. When I try to use it in the matlab interpreter in the terminal nothing happens:

```
>>imshow('<path to image>')
>>
```

No image pops up, no output is returned.

I've also tried this way (although the documentation says you can pass a filename to the imshow function)

```
>>I = imread('<path to image>')
<outputs numerical values of each pixel>
>>imshow(I)
>>
```

Same thing, nothing happens, what am I missing here?

I have triple checked to make sure the image exists at that path. I've tried this with jpgs and pngs.

I'm using matlab 2017a on Ubuntu 16.04

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the image path you're using?

Comment: @Aziz, for testing, I downloaded this image to my downloads folder https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png and saved it as `test.png`. I have tried both the relative path from the directory the image is in `I = imread('test.png'); imshow(I)` and the absolute path `I = imread('/home/<my-username>/Downloads/test.png'); imshow(I)` This is really baffling me.

Comment: Try running this: `license('test', 'image_toolbox')`. What's the output you get?

Comment: @Aziz It says 
    `ans =

          1`

Comment: and this `which -all imshow` ?

Comment: @Aziz `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/toolbox/matlab/images/imshow.m`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141605/discussion-between-matthew-drill-and-aziz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are launching MATLAB with `-nodisplay` which suppresses the display of *all* graphics. If you'd like to launch MATLAB without the desktop, but would like to display interactive figures, you'll want to use the `-nodesktop` option instead

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash
```